# Property [jenis_penyedia] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

Property [jenis_penyedia] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
   @php $no = 1; @endphp
        @foreach($profile as $p)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->jenis->jenis_penyedia }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->nama }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->no_ktp }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->npwp }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->bank }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->no_rek }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->email }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->no_telp }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->keahlian }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->pengalaman }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->alamat }}</td>
              <td>{{ $p->pendidikan }}</td>
              <td>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eager load your jenis to Profile.

```
$profile = Profile::with('jenis')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$p->jenis` is an Eloquent Collection. This Collection may contain many Jenis model instances (because of the `hasMany` relationship definition). Those models have the attribute `jenis_penyedia`, not the Collection.

You would need to decide which model you want to get that attribute of since there potentially are many, or none. Maybe using the first one works for your needs:

```
{{ $p->jenis->first()->jenis_penyedia ?? "some default value" }}
```